# Django Python Where to add Auxiliary Functions to not repeat code?

Tags: python, django

I come from native POO programming languages and I'm new in Python, also Django.

I see that in Django they put all code from an app in same views.py or models.py.

Now I'm in a view called:

```
def create_ticket(self):
    ....
```

And inside I have this code

```
        is_staff=User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id).is_staff
    if is_staff==1:
        R_Client_Accountant = LinkUserContable.objects.filter(contable=mongoId)
        print(R_Client_Accountant)
        accountantList = []
        for relation in R_Client_Accountant:
            try:
                rmongosql = RMongoSql.objects.get(mongoId=relation.user.id)
                user = User.objects.get(pk=rmongosql.helpdeskId)
                accountantList.append((user.id,user.username))
            except:
                pass
    else:
        R_Client_Accountant = LinkUserContable.objects.filter(user=mongoId)
        accountantList = []
        for relation in R_Client_Accountant:
            try:
                rmongosql = RMongoSql.objects.get(mongoId=relation.contable.id)
                user = User.objects.get(pk=rmongosql.helpdeskId)
                accountantList.append((user.id,user.username))
            except:
                pass
```

As you can see I repeat code inside the 'try' just exchanging {user XOR contable} 
If I want to write a function passing by parameter this {user XOR contable} where should I place it ?

To me, in corresponding model from models.py is not correct because there are so much code lines referring to different models and views.py is just for view functions right ?

Regards,
Víctor.

Comment: You can make a `utils.py` to add utilities. But development in Django often results in "fat models". That is not inherently bad.

Comment: Python *is* an OOP language.

Comment: The only difference between your two cases is the `relation.<type>.id`, so you could just define `if is_staff==1: attr = "user" else: attr = "contable"` and in your query, do `mongoId=getattr(relation, attr).id`

Comment: @dirkgroten that worked perfectly, thanks :D

Also I created an utils.py, I'm not quite happy with this approach but maybe is better than put it anywhere else...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `getattr` function to use a string to get the required attribute `getattr(relation, relation_attr)`

your function would look like this

```
def create_ticket(self):
    is_staff=User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id).is_staff
    if is_staff==1:
        relation_attr = 'user'
    else:
        relation_attr = 'contable'
    R_Client_Accountant = LinkUserContable.objects.filter(contable=mongoId)
    print(R_Client_Accountant)
    accountantList = []
    for relation in R_Client_Accountant:
        try:
            rmongosql = RMongoSql.objects.get(mongoId=getattr(relation, relation_attr).id)
            user = User.objects.get(pk=rmongosql.helpdeskId)
            accountantList.append((user.id, user.username))
        except:
            pass
```